# SASS @for - Through vs. To

Tags: loops, for-loop, sass

I'm quite new to SASS and I have difficulty understanding the difference between the two statements:

```
@for $i from 1 through 3
```

vs.

```
@for $i from 1 to 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can read the difference: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for

> [...] If **to** is used, the final number is excluded; if **through** is used,
>   it's included.

Then, when you use `through`:

```
@for $i from 1 through 3{
  div{
    content:$i;
  }
}
```

you create this output:

```
div {
  content: 1;
}

div {
  content: 2;
}

div {
  content: 3;
}
```

Instead, using `to`:

```
@for $i from 1 to 3{
  div{
    content:$i;
  }
}
```

You create this output:

```
div {
  content: 1;
}

div {
  content: 2;
}
```